What is difference between distributed monolith vs modular monolith architecture?
what is the difference between distributed monolith and modular monolith architectures? don't both essentially share a single database? what make the modular monolith a viable option? and how does it compare with microservices patterns?
How are boundaries enforced in the modular monolith?


don't both essentially share a single database?

No, distributed monolith is not about using single database, it is an antipattern in microservices architecture when the microservices are tightly coupled (i.e. when you can't change one microservice without changing the other(s)) which leads to negating the benefits of the architecture, like independent deployments and so on. That is the reason why microservices architecture is very sensitive to correct decomposition (things like DDD and patterns like decompose by business capability and decompose by subdomain)

what make the modular monolith a viable option? and how does it compare with microservices patterns?

Modular monoliths use similar principle as microservices - splitting the code into loosely coupled parts, but without moving those parts into separate codebases/deployment units. They also are not restricted to a single/shared database, though it is quite more common with this approach than with microservices.

How are boundaries enforced in the modular monolith?

Usually by conventions and strict design/code review. In some cases some automatic tools can be written depended on what language/stack/tools are used. Some patterns can be useful too for example the mediator one.

when would it be preferrable to use one over the other?

Microservices have some downsides compared to a monolithic applications - higher operational cost (you need better deployment system and more scalable one), performance penalty of switching from in-process communications to different RPCs, higher costs and lower speed of initial development (sometimes it is a big factor when you need to ship a MVP fast). There are a lot of factors which might affect a decision to select a monolithic architecture over microservices one:

Team size (arguably one of the main problems microservices solve is organizational one), for smaller teams monolith might be preferrable
Feature richness - for apps with smaller feature sets monolith can be a way to go
Scalability requirements/specifics - depended on what and how is needed to be scaled you might select one over another. For example when you have a lot of "small" clients it might be easier to shard per client i.e. deploy a new instance of application per client/group of clients rather than scale parts of the system, hence monolith would be an option to consider
Performance requirements/specifics - application can process a lot of data so penalty of RPC can become noticable, for example the case from a year ago when Prime Video moved to a monolith from microservices (see for example
Reduce costs by 90% by moving from microservices to monolith: Amazon internal case study raises eyebrows)

On the other hand monolith apps have downsides too, so if you decide to go with monolithic architecture in order to mitigate them you can look into using modular monolith - i.e. you split parts of the application into services but "internal" ones (i.e. they are still a single app/exe/dll/deployment) and then enforce the boundaries (this is a very good question you have asked).

I am not quite following what is the difference exactly between the modular monolith vs the microservices? when would it be preferrable to use one over the other? could you give an illustration or example please?

@Linkx_lair " what is the difference exactly between ..." - there is not much to say here except what was already said in the answer- modular monolith is a single deployable unit (i.e. single exe, dll, etc.), it is not split into separate deployments (and repos), while microservices - are. As for other questions - I will try to update the post.

@Linkx_lair please see the update.

Many thanks for such a comprehensive overview Guru!
